# Searching for text string in a variable

Tags: vba

I have to search for multiple text strings in an Excel column (one string at a time). This column has got around 200K values. So if I search through this column 50 times , it takes long time using the "Find" command in VBA.

I am looking for an alternative method to make this search more efficient. Probably, reading this column once in a variable and then search this variable for the text strings I want to. With this method, I hope the searches will be faster than searching in an Excel sheet column itself.

Please suggest the best option to accomplish it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you first reading the values into an array?  Post up some code.

Comment: Whats your code so far?

Comment: I am just using the "Find" function to search a string in the Excel sheet. And this is a bit slow when you search thousands of cells for hundreds of different strings. This is why I wanted to use a variable where I could load all the column, and do an efficient search inside it. I have used the 'INSTR' function and it made remarkable difference to the times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something small to start with:
Open Excel file and write some values in Range `E10:E34`. Make sure that one of the values is `Plot`.
Then run the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim varArray        As Variant
    Dim strToSearch     As String: strToSearch = "Plot"
    Dim varVal          As Variant
    Dim lngCounter      As Long : lngCounter

    varArray = Range("E10:E34")

    For Each varVal In varArray
        If varVal = strToSearch Then
            Debug.Print varVal
            Debug.Print lngCounter
            Exit For
        End If
    Next varVal
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
End Sub
```

It will give you the row of the `E10:E34` range, on which the value is to be found.

The code is not finished. You have to think of the following:

1. What happens, if we have the value more than once;
2. What happens, if we want array with more than one columns;
3. What happens, if the range should be flexible;
4. What happens, if we just know the start of the value in the cell, but we still want it - e.g. the value is `Plot` and in the cell we have `Plotnik` and we want to get it somehow.
5. Anything else.

Comment: Thank you Vityata. I tried this method, and it works fine. However, I am currently using the INSTR function which is more efficient for my requirement.